# why autoscaling is not creating in the cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

While creating **AutoScalingGroup** by using CloudFormation template I am facing this error ,the error is :

```
Failed to receive 1 resource signal(s) for the current batch. Each resource 
signal timeout is counted as a FAILURE.
```

How can I resolve this issue? please suggest me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That error is suggesting that the EC2 instance(s) created by Auto Scaling failed to pass their health checks, or perhaps failed to complete their User Data. However, there isn't enough detail in your question to be able to know the cause. Seems similar to: [error on stack creation (cloudformation) "Failed to receive 1 resource signal(s) for the current batch" · Issue #19 · lambci/ecs](https://github.com/lambci/ecs/issues/19)

Comment: Can you paste your CloudFormation xml ?